# How can I get information about CPU loading on UNIX, using php?

Tags: php, unix, cpu

I need to get the information (loading CPU in this moment) from server and write this in the variable. `sys_getloadavg()` returns an array with three samples (last 1, 5 and 15 minutes), but I need loading CPU in this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy, I had to turn to the first array variable:

```
$cpu_loading_array = sys_getloadavg();

$cpu_loading = $cpu_loading_array[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a direct way of doing it. My suggestion of a work around is to use a function like `exec` or its equivalents. With a `exec` you can invoke a unix command like `top` to get the desirable stats. Then you have to parse the return value of `exec` and get the information you are searching for. There is also the file `/proc/stat` which you can read an get the information you want.